# Not implemented error when i tried to resample a data frame with datetime index

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, resampling, dataframe

This is how my data frame:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 381494 entries, 2013-07-05 01:11:11 to 2013-07-16 12:59:59
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Value_x       381494  non-null values
Value_y       381494  non-null values
Difference    381494  non-null values
dtypes: float64(3)
```

When i try to resample, i got a not *"implemented error"*.

my code is just e.g **b.resample('5Min', how = 'ohlc')**

Comment: What is the question? Could you include output of df.head() ?

Comment: I think i got the answer for this post. Basically, ohlc does not support multiple column data frame when resampling. Therefore, i convert df to series and it's work! @AndyHayden